# How to teach Intellisense about the existence of <tr> and <td>?

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, intellisense, code-completion

Intellisense has macro for making new table:

[image]

Yet when I try to create new row, it forces the `<strong>` tag:

[image]

I actually have to press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, otherwise the `<strong>` is inserted if I type `>`. I have similar problems with `<th>`, where `<math>` is inserted instead.

Is there a way to add HTML element to known elements of intellisense?

Comment: I tested it in my VS community 2017 15.4.0 or run it as safe mode, cannot reproduce this issue, please check this: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Atv5QNuFrncKmCLejYPc_xsJoLy7. You can try to 1. restart VS and create a new solution to test, 2. run the VS with safe mode 3. clean up the cache folder: %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_xxx\ to troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 0):

VS should totally know about these elements.  It sounds like the HTML schema has somehow been corrupted.  You can try to delete the HTML schema cache and see if that fixes the problem.  To do this, go to `%AppData%\Microsoft\Visual Studio\15.0_<InstanceID>\` and remove (or rename) the `GeneratedSchemas` folder.